# Actualizador de ficheros python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Estoy tratando de hacer un auto-actualizador de ficheros python. La idea es que a las 00.00 todos los días, o en el inicio de la ejecución del script se conecte a una url que contiene una lista de ficheros.

Luego ha de visitar la url de cada fichero y descargarlo a local machacando lo que haya de forma que siempre tenga la versión más actualizada de los ficheros.

Con esta idea, tengo dos problemas:

1. si ejecuto script.py, también debe actualizar script.py con la versión más reciente. Pero al haberlo ejecutado ya no va a actualizar los posibles cambios hasta la proxima ejecución. Hay manera de auto relanzarse a sí mismo?
2. He logrado leer la lista de ficheros y que visite la url de cada fichero, pero lo que descarga no es el contenido del .py en el servidor web, sino que descarga código html del hosting. Por supuesto he revisado la url y es correcta.

Os dejo código hasta el momento:

```
import requests, os, wget

fileList = requests.get("url/to/file/update.list")
files = fileList.text.split("#")

for file in files:

    url = "url/to/file/"+file
    wget.download(url, os.path.join(basePath, "test", file))
```

Y un ejemplo del fichero update.list

```
file1.py#file2.py#file3.py
```

Comment: si no te descarga el archivo entonces ese no es problema de tu script sino del servidor que envía un contenido no esperado

Comment: Toda la razón. Comprobé simplemente que la url generada era correcta, pero no se me ocurrió probar si un navegador devolvía el contenido esperado. Bueno, pues a ver qué más se me ocurre para programar este auto-updater. Gracias @Christian

Comment: investiga si ese servicio no proporciona una api para poder ver el contenido del archivo